# Dynamically changing File name through Name Manager

Tags: excel

I'm pulling data from another files. I've dynamically set the file name as `file_name` so that in case i want to keep the formula but pull it from another file, i can just change the file name in the name manager. All the files are of the same format and in the same path.

But when i refresh the data, its not being pulled. it keeps saying #N/A.

```
=INDEX(‘C:\Users\zaid\Documents\[+file_name]Forecast 
Jan'!$1:$1048576,MATCH(C2,’C:\Users\zaid\Documents\[+file_name]Forecast 
Jan'!A:A,0),MATCH(D2,’C:\Users\zaid\Documents\[+file_name]Forecast 
Jan'!$3:$3,0))
```

I expect the output to pull from the file name set in the dynamic field, but the values aren't changing even after refreshing.

Comment: Excel has no idea what `+file_name` means in that formula. It would have to be `\["& file_name & "]Forecast` for any chance of this working if you're assigning the formula from VBA code.

Comment: I've set the file_name in name manager as the file name, shouldn't Excel be able extract the information from that?

Comment: [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-current-Excel-file-name-path-or-worksheet-in-a-cell-186833c6-c899-4912-a14c-240c2eb51e0b) is the Microsoft documentation on how to get the filename.